# Can you use INNER JOIN with a primary key?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, foreign-keys, primary-key

I have two tables with a one-to-one relationship.  Table1 has a composite primary key consisting of about 4 columns.  Table2's foreign key is set to Table1's primary key.

When I try the following UPDATE clause, I am getting an error:

```
UPDATE Table2
SET column1 = fakeTable.c1
FROM Table2 INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT Table1.primaryKey
        , (Table1.column3 + Table1.column4) AS c1
        FROM Table1
    ) AS c1
ON Table2.foreignKey = fakeTable.primaryKey
```

Am I not allowed to reference keys as if they are columns?

Comment: There's only one reference to `fakeTable` in the statement, so that is one source of error.  Did you mean to write `AS fakeTable` or `SET column1 = c1.c1`?

Comment: SQL Server 2008.  Good catch on the missing reference to fakeTable in the ON statement.  Unfortunately, that didn't fix things.  I think I need to actually reference the columns that make up the keys.  I thought the whole point of keys was to avoid having to concatenate columns!

Comment: Invalid object name 'Table2'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you need to list all the fields individually.  But you can avoid the sub-query that you have...

```
UPDATE
  Table2
SET
  column1 = Table1.column3 + Table1.column4
FROM
  Table2
INNER JOIN
  Table1
    ON  Table2.foreignKey1 = Table1.primaryKey1
    AND Table2.foreignKey2 = Table1.primaryKey2
    AND Table2.foreignKey3 = Table1.primaryKey3
    AND Table2.foreignKey4 = Table1.primaryKey4
```

**EDIT**

Response to comment:
- `I thought the whole point of keys was to avoid having to concatenate columns!`

Keys aren't a time saving device, they're data integrity devices.

A primary key is a unique identifier.  I can be a composite or not, but the important thing is that it is unique and not nullable.

A foreign key is also a data integrity device.  It ensure that if data refers to something in another table, it actually *must* exist in that other table.

Comment: This worked!  Thank you.  I knew I was overcomplicating it.  Should I create a new column in each table that is a concatenation of the columns I used to create the keys?  That would help avoid all of the AND checks.

Comment: @eek - In general, `NO`.  If the individual fields mean something individually, stick as you are.  Stuffing multiple items into the same field is a SQL Anti-Pattern and will often cause more problems in the future than it's worth.  The closest approach I'd advocate is to have another IDENTITY column in Table1, and foreign key to that.  You can *still* put a unique key on the 4 identifying fields.  This is called a surrogate key (another key in place of a composite key).

Comment: Hoever, if you add an identity column to make joining simpler, be sure to put a unique index onthe four columns that were orginally your primary key!

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't reference keys as if they were columns.  You will need to list out all of the columns in both the PK and the FK... in both your sub `select`, and in your `join`'s `on` clause.

Comment: Do you recommend concatenating the columns so that I don't have to list so many AND operators?

Comment: @eek142 I wouldn't recommend that... instead I'd second Dems suggestion for an `IDENTITY` column.